# How to force Maven to ignore <repository> from dependcy pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, nexus

I had a pom in my dependencies which contains :

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-releases</id>
   <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release-remote/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>public-jboss</id>
  <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>spring-plugin-releases</id>
  <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
</repository>
```

and a settings.xml in $M2_HOME which contains :

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>ignore-repositories</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>public-jboss</id>
          <url>http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
          <url>http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-plugin-releases</id>
          <url>http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
  </profile>
</profiles>
</settings>
```

I tried also with `repositories/repository`:

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>ignore-repositories</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>public-jboss</id>
          <url>http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
          <url>http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-plugin-releases</id>
          <url>http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
  </profile>
</profiles>
</settings>
```

But that never take mynexus when maven resolve this pom example :

```
[INFO] --- wildfly-swarm-plugin:2016.10.0:package (package) @ microservice-attendee ---
Downloading: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/org/wildfly/swarm/fraction-list/2016.10.0/fraction-list-2016.10.0.pom
Downloaded: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/org/wildfly/swarm/fraction-list/2016.10.0/fraction-list-2016.10.0.pom (2 KB at 16.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/org/wildfly/swarm/tools/2016.10.0/tools-2016.10.0.pom
Downloaded: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/org/wildfly/swarm/tools/2016.10.0/tools-2016.10.0.pom (2 KB at 215.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/com/eclipsesource/minimal-json/minimal-json/0.9.4/minimal-json-0.9.4.pom
Downloaded: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/com/eclipsesource/minimal-json/minimal-json/0.9.4/minimal-json-0.9.4.pom (5 KB at 53.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/org/wildfly/swarm/fraction-list/2016.10.0/fraction-list-2016.10.0.jar
Downloading: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/com/eclipsesource/minimal-json/minimal-json/0.9.4/minimal-json-0.9.4.jar
Downloading: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/org/wildfly/swarm/tools/2016.10.0/tools-2016.10.0.jar
Downloaded: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/org/wildfly/swarm/fraction-list/2016.10.0/fraction-list-2016.10.0.jar (171 KB at 12211.5 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/com/eclipsesource/minimal-json/minimal-json/0.9.4/minimal-json-0.9.4.jar (30 KB at 1859.1 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/org/wildfly/swarm/tools/2016.10.0/tools-2016.10.0.jar (65 KB at 4276.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.3/javax.json-1.0.3.pom
Downloading: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.3/javax.json-1.0.3.pom
Downloaded: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.3/javax.json-1.0.3.pom (10 KB at 392.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/glassfish/json/1.0.3/json-1.0.3.pom
Downloading: http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/org/glassfish/json/1.0.3/json-1.0.3.pom
...
```

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help.

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-45-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve to which you think "ignoring" a repository is a solution? Are you trying to force a dependency to download from mynexus but it is instead downloading from the jboss nexus?

Comment: The mirrorOf with the asterik means to redirect all request to the given URL http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/ ...

Comment: @Saku Are you sure your Maven is reading the correct settings.xml and not some other one from a different directory?

Comment: i'm trying to force a dependency to download from mynexus but it is instead downloading from the jboss nexus

Comment: @JF yes all jars come from mynexus, just a few pass on respository from pom of dependencies

Answer (score 2):

instead of ignore repo you can make the specific repo in your settings.xml profile like this

```
    <settings>
      <mirrors>
        <mirror>
          <id>nexus</id>
          <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
          <url>http://mynexus/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </mirror>
      </mirrors>
      <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>specify-repositories</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
          <repositories>
            <repository>
               <id>spring-releases</id>
               <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release-remote/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
              <id>public-jboss</id>
              <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
              <id>spring-plugin-releases</id>
              <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
        </repository>
        </repositories>
      </profile>
    </profiles>
    </settings>
```

Comment: Hi, It's my second settings.xml of my question. That don't work

Comment: you can find a good request here : https://developer.jboss.org/message/576851?_sscc=t